# paste() after unpacking ellipsis won't print listed arguments

Tags: r

I created the function `mad_libs` in which a pass an ellipsis as argument and unpack it. The function "works", as it does print and apparently there is nothing wrong with it, but I don't get the arguments I pass.

Function as follows:

```
   mad_libs <- function(...){
            args <- list(...)

            place <- args[["place"]]
            adjective <- args[["adjective"]]
            noun <- args[["noun"]]

            paste("News from", place, "today where", adjective, "students took 
to the streets in protest of the new", noun, "being installed on campus.")
    }
```

Let's say I pass `mad_libs("NIFLHEIM", "possessed", "fountain")` or whatever arguments, always in between " ", I get:

```
    [1] "News from  today where  students took to the streets in protest 
of the new  being installed on campus."
```

Arguments are not printed.

I've had printing issues because my OS is in Br Portuguese, but this doesn't seem to be the case in which spelling rules would be a problem.

Running R 3.3.1 on RStudio, Windows 10 in Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: It works fine for me.  I tried `mad_libs(place = "the moon", adjective = "hyperactive", noun = "SAS data server")`.  Did you name the arguments that you passed in to `mad_libs`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I tried positional matching only. It does work naming the arguments, but I don't see why it wouldn't otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably study [argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching).

If you want both positional matching and name matching to work, you can use `do.call` like this:

```
mad_libs <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)

  fun <- function(place, adjective, noun)
    paste("News from", place, "today where", adjective, "students took to the streets in protest of the new", noun, "being installed on campus.")

  do.call(fun, args)
}

mad_libs("NIFLHEIM", "possessed", "fountain")
#[1] "News from NIFLHEIM today where possessed students took to the streets in protest of the new fountain being installed on campus."

mad_libs(adjective = "possessed", "NIFLHEIM", "fountain")
#[1] "News from NIFLHEIM today where possessed students took to the streets in protest of the new fountain being installed on campus."
```

Of course, if there is no compelling reason to create `args` you can simply pass on the ellipses:

```
mad_libs <- function(...){

  fun <- function(place, adjective, noun)
    paste("News from", place, "today where", adjective, "students took to the streets in protest of the new", noun, "being installed on campus.")

  fun(...)
}
```

Comment: I was studying argument matching, as you mentioned, and also unpacking ellipses. Your sollution looks more interesting than the one I tried and a lot more economic too. Thank you for helping!